# How to retrieve JSON with different value type using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson to deserialize a JSON file that is coming from an external API I cannot change, unfortunately.

This JSON has two possible values for the `related` attribute: one as a list, when it's populated:

```
"related": [{
        "ID": "1694"
    }, {
        "ID": "1631"
    }, {
        "ID": "1628"
}]
```

And `false` if it's not.

```
"related": [false]
```

In the second case I receive a `JsonMappingException`:

```
Could not read document: Can not construct instance of xxx.xxx.xxx.RelatedDTO: 
no boolean/Boolean-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from boolean value (false)
```

**How can I manage both possible values?**

This is what I have right now.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class MagazinePostDTO {

    private List<MagazineRelatedDTO> related;

    // other properties....

}
```

And `MagazineRelatedDTO` is:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.*;

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class MagazineRelatedDTO {

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private Integer id;

}
```

Comment: can you share your existing code ?

Comment: @Ravi I've updated the question...

Comment: Should be possible using a custom deserializer (f.i. see http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

Comment: @Napolux Please do share your solution, if it different than answer posted, otherwise consider accepting it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved with a [custom deserializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization): I'm returning an empty object if I'm not able to deserialize it properly.

```
public class RelatedDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MagazineRelatedDTO> {

    @Override
    public MagazineRelatedDTO deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        try {
            MagazineRelatedDTO value = p.readValueAs(new TypeReference<MagazineRelatedDTO>() {});
            return value;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new MagazineRelatedDTO();
        }
    }
}
```

You then have to define it in your DTO.

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class MagazinePostDTO {

    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = RelatedDeserializer.class)
    private List<MagazineRelatedDTO> related;
    // other properties....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, You can read the property in try block on exception i.e. failure case, read `Boolean` object.

```
try
{
   // code here and store to POJO
   MagazinePostDTO postDTO = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, MagazinePostDTO.class);
   // some coding
}
catch (JsonMappingException e)
{
    //failure case, read Boolean 
    Boolean bool = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Boolean.class);
    // some coding 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like the error message implies, you can have a Boolean-argument constructor for `MagazineRelatedDTO`.  in this constructor you can either set some default value to the `id` property or even do nothing, in which case `MagazinePostDTO` will be initialized with a list that contains one item with a null `id` property.

```
public class MagazineRelatedDTO
{
    public MagazineRelatedDTO() {}
    public MagazineRelatedDTO(boolean b) {}
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private Integer id = null;
}
```